# Create same size buttons

Tags: html, css

Code below creates two buttons with different size in html form. How to make these buttons same size?

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="btn"">
<input type="button" value="superLongButon"">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean both buttons should have the same width?

Comment: setting a width attr `input{width:200px}`

Comment: Apply same size to them?

Comment: Take a look at some introductory tutorials on CSS.  You can use that to style your HTML elements.

Comment: Just add a width property to your input elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a style class and use it in both button.

```
.clsButton {
  //Put your style declaration here
}

<form>
<input type="button" value="btn" class="clsButton">
<input type="button" value="superLongButon" class="clsButton">
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

How wide a button appears on a page is controlled using CSS.

There are at least 3 ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

`1.` Inline CSS:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" style="width:200px;" value="btn"">
    <input type="button" style="width:200px;" value="superLongButon"">
</form>
```

`2.` Adding an HTML class and creating a CSS rule for that class:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" class="frmBtn" value="btn"">
    <input type="button" class="frmBtn" value="superLongButon"">
</form>
```

Then you add this in your CSS file:

```
.frmBtn {
    width:200px
}
```

`3.` CSS only (no need to edit your html):

```
form input[type='button'] {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px; //or as wide as you want them to be
}
```

Number 1 should generally be avoided where possible as you lose the consistency and performance benefits of using an external style sheet.

Comment: You don't strictly need an inline block, an inline element will also respect the width value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to achieve this behavior.

Check the following example:

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}
input,
button {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <button>small button</button>

  <button>this is the bigger button</button>

</form>

<form>

  <input type="button" value="small button">

  <input type="button" value="this is the bigger button">

</form>
```

Comment: A perfect solution. Thanks.

Comment: what if I need some space between them?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task. I'd suggest in that case to count letters of text for each button, multiply the size to a certain width, and use the maximal value as an inline value for the width.

Example:

```
const buttonOne = "save" // 4
const buttonTwo = "save with notification" // 22
const maxLength = Math.max(buttonOne.length, buttonTwo.length)
const letterWidth = 5 // play with this value
const additionalWidth = 3; // play with it to find the value that suits your needs
const maxWidth = maxLength * letterWidth + additionalWidth;

// React
// I use 'ch' here, because 'ch' is width of 0 (in css)
<button style={{width: "${maxWidth}ch"}}>{{buttonOne}}</button>
<button style={{width: "${maxWidth}ch"}}>{{buttonTwo}}</button>
```